# Is it possible to pass var received from API call in Javascript to php?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api

I am making an API call and receive a response. I save some part of the response in a variable in Javascript. I would like to pass that variable to a php file "main_page.php". I was trying to use ajax inside the function to use the variable and pass it to the php file and then echo it in php file but it doesn't seem to work. Is is even possible? If so can you please tell me how. Thanks!

This is my javascript file that makes an API call and returns a response body. I am trying to pass var urlVal to my php file. I don't need to print it out in php. it is just for testing purposes. I echo it to make sure it s there. So far I am unable to pass it to php as i dont see anything printed out in the console.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindButtons); 

    function bindButtons(){
            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function(event){

                    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req.open("GET","https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=" + apiKey, true);


                    req.addEventListener('load', function(){
                    if(req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400)
                        {
                            var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                            console.log(response);
                            var urlVal = document.getElementById('showname').textContent = response.hdurl;


                            $.ajax({
                             type: 'POST',
                             url:'main_page.php', 
                                 data:{
                                    'total' : $("#showname").textContent(),},
                                 success: function(response){
                            }} );

                    req.send(null);


                    event.preventDefault(); }
                    )
                    }
```

This is some of the code i have in my php file "main_page.php" :

```
<div id= "second">
            <h2>PREVIEW</h2>
            <p class = "api_desc"> <span id= "showname"> <span> </p> 
        </div>
<?php

        echo $_POST['total'];
?>
```

Comment: You won't see it output into the console; but check your Network tab and inspect the AJAX request and its response…

Comment: It looks like I m getting a json object back fine but cannot see anything after this point

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Although, what exactly is to be accomplished is unclear. Here is one working approach to build off of...

main_page.php:

```
<?php
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        echo $_POST['total'];
      }
?>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id='submit'> SUBMIT! </button>
  <BR><BR><BR>
  <div id= "second">
    <h2>PREVIEW</h2>
    <p class = "api_desc"> <span id= "showname"> </span> </p> 
  </div>
</body>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindButtons); 
function bindButtons(){
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click',function(event){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
              console.log(response.hdurl);
              var urlVal = document.getElementById('showname').innerText = response.hdurl;
              //console.log($("#showname").text());

              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'main_page.php', 
                data: {'total' : $("#showname").text()},
                success: function(response,status,xhr){
                    alert(response)
                }
              });
          }
        };
        req.open("GET", "api.json", true);
        req.send();
      });
    }
</script>
</html>
```

api.json:

```
{"id":"one","data":"stuff","hdurl":"http://www.example.com/"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was trying to incorporate your code into mine but no result so far.Since I m using an API call the hdurl values doensnt exist in the HTML therefore may be I fail to use your code. Basically, everything works up to the line where i get response.hdrul saved in var urlVal. i just need somehow to pass this value to main_page.php into php variable so i can use it to send to sql DB. I have a form in my php that i use to later send this variable to DB. I have tried to use ajax part right after i assign value of response.hdrul to var urlVal but it is not working

Comment: use **console.log(response)** and look for the attribute name. Make sure that hdurl is accessible from response.hdurl ...